# Cron not working on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with Python and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have built a simple Django app and successfully deployed it to Beanstalk. The app uses a PostgreSQL backend on an RDS instance. From a browser, I can successfully access the admin and create and delete models inside of it. However, I'm also trying to run a cron that updates the database. I installed the cron on the server, but it didn't work. So I then shelled in, ran the commands manually and got the following error: **Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?**

From my Googling, I'm guessing this has something to do with either security groups, allowed hosts or [JDBC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html). Perhaps allowing the Beanstalk's EC2 instance and RDS instance to interactive with each other. But I'm lost. I tried the instructions from this [AWS tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html).

For the record, the script that the cron runs works perfectly when run locally as `python manage.py runscript scrape`.

Other stuff:
[The tutorial I followed for deploying my app](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).
[The tutorial I followed for the cron](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv/)

**Cron**

```
* * * * * /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.4 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py runscript scrape
```

**Database part of settings.py**

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'db',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use "python3" instead of "python3.4" in the cron and then check if it runs

Comment: Am also noticing another error: KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'. Looks like the environment variable might be undefined for whatever reason.

Comment: python3 is still causing the error

Comment: Check below that is how you run a python using cron job

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you run a python script.

It is a question on cron.
First is add a SHEBANG line on top of your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Make your script executable with `chmod +x`

And do a crontab -e and add `0 0 */2 * * /path/to/your/pythonscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. I forgot to actually set the environment variables in the AWS console. What can I say, it has been a long day.

Comment: You'd better set them as exports in your ~/.bashrc so you don't have to re-instantiate them all the time, like `export RDS_DB_NAME='yourdbname'`. Also checking  pg_hba.conf for peer set to  trust and restarting `service postgresql restart` might be helpful.